# Heroku's crashed using Node.js

Tags: node.js, heroku

I have been trying to deploy my web site. It works on my local computer but when I deploy it to Heroku it doesn't work.

This is Heroku's log:

```
2022-01-12T09:31:04.854187+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2022-01-12T09:31:05.082730+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2022-01-12T15:07:15.575516+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2022-01-12T15:07:17.952102+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2022-01-12T15:07:19.220594+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! missing script: start
2022-01-12T15:07:19.224923+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2022-01-12T15:07:19.225102+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2022-01-12T15:07:19.225149+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2022-01-12T15_07_19_221Z-debug.log
2022-01-12T15:07:19.394790+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2022-01-12T15:07:19.459851+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

Comment: `missing script: start` - _do_ you define a start script? That's what Heroku [requires by default](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#default-web-process-type). Give a [mre].

Comment: You may also specify your process in a `Procfile` if you prefer. Heroku uses that in preference to a start script if it exists.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a `start` script in your `package.json`. As an example:

```
{
  "name": "your-project",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Your project description",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node src/index.js" // or wherever your `index.js` is
  },
  ...
}
```